# Relative import compatibility issue py2 and py3

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

I have following package stricture:

```
foo:
   __init__.py
   soft:
       __init__.py
       access.py
```

**init**.py has following line

```
from . import access
```

when I'm running the package foo.soft, it is giving an error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name access
```

But it works if I remove . and make the second **init** as following:

```
import access
```

> But py3 requires the relative import to have ".". How to resolve this
>   py2 and py3 compatibility issue?

Answer (score 0):

It has resolved by adding:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```